# why admin panel folder is not accessible even if i have defined in default application folder

Tags: codeigniter

i want to create admin panel so i have created admin folder inside application folder(C:\wamp\www\new\application\admin) and inside admin folder i have placed model view controllers of admin and outside the admin folder i.e inside (C:\wamp\www\new\application)application folder i have placed default user model view controllers , and in index.php file which is located at (C:\wamp\www\new) i have written following code

```
$application_folder = 'application';
$application_folder = 'application/admin';
```

my route in config is to welcome controller which is same in both application controller and admin controller , application controller takes to user view where as admin controller takes to admin login view

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
```

but there comes error when i open browser to start this project

[image: this is the error]

i dont know what is going wrong plz help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not change the `index.php` unless needed.

The variable `$application_folder` is used to define the application folder for the codeigniter project. You can't define multiple application folder in a single project.
In the code you are assigning two values to `$application_folder` and the later one, that is `'application/admin'` is taken. So the codeigniter will look for config file in `application/admin/config` directory. That is why you are getting a `Failed to open stream` error.

For the admin panel you may create a directory inside your controllers directory called `application/controllers/admin` and put all admin panel controllers in that. More to that you can have a routing controller  `application/controllers/admin.php` the index function of which will be called when user enters the url `yourwebsite.com/admin/`.

Hope the things are now clear for you.